# flutter:To get the length of an item in cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am totally new to flutter and firestore.so please help with this.I want to get how much  number of items from userCarts possess in Firestore.In current uid there are 3 items in userCart .so i want to get result as 3[image: firestore structure]

```
QuerySnapshot s= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();
int docs=s.docs.length;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all when you call
`QuerySnapshot s= FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();`  you are not getting QuerySnapshot you are getting DocumentSnapshot, you should be doing like this

```
DocumentSnapshot doc= await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(user.uid).get();

List<dynamic> userCart = doc.data()['userCart'];//here you already got the list

int length = userCart.length;
```

Note - I used `await` so this should be inside asynchronous function.